# Render Streaming Received Sample is not getting my stream in unity

Tags: unity

I am just testing the [**new render streaming package in unity 2020.3.22**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.renderstreaming@3.1/manual/installation.html) but sadly the receiver (HTML page) is not receiving my camera stream. While both consoles (web and unity) are clear there is no error. Currently, I have a Main camera which has a camera Stream Sender is attached and its is showing two pieces of info:

[image: Camera properties]
While on another empty object I have attached

1. Render Streaming
2. Broadcast
3. Broadcast Sample
   [image: Render streaming properties]

One strange thing I found is that the sample scene (Receiver) is working fine. But the same setup which I have made is not working. Probably the reason is given in the above screenshot. why it is happening?
[image: Render streaming properties]

While the original documentation has also been missed that you have to attach the broadcast sample script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have same issue and I drag the script component instead of maincamera gameobject and issue is solved. try this.

Thanks

Comment: Bravo! I don't how i missed this thing of assignment. Thanks, and very good start on gameDev.

Comment: After connecting with receiver (html page) did you get No camera rendering error on  of the game view? inside unity?

Comment: yes got this error. but this is on editor. not in build